# Copying an Ubuntu on VMWare to Real Computer without any lose

Tags: 15.10, iso, clone, copy

### Situation

I have an **Ubuntu 15.10** with **programs**, **themes**, **apps**, **settings** *etc.* I've installed.

But I have installed to my Ubuntu **unnecessary** things for real computer too. *(like VMWare tools and drivers.)*

### What I want to

I want to **copy** and **paste** my **Ubuntu** from **VMWare** to **real computer without any lose**. *(gtk themes, my desktop files, installed apps etc.)*

### So...

How can I **copy** **Ubuntu** like this and install my real computer **without** any **lose** but **compatible** with **new computer** and new computer's **drivers**.

**Thanks!**